# Are all xserver-xorg-video-* packages required?

Tags: drivers, xorg, dpkg

Long story short, somehow I ended up with bunch of xorg-video packages while I only have Intel GPU on my system:

```
xserver-xorg-video-all                          install
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                       install
xserver-xorg-video-ati                          install
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                        install
xserver-xorg-video-intel                        install
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                      install
xserver-xorg-video-radeon                       install
xserver-xorg-video-vesa                         install
xserver-xorg-video-vmware                       install
```

Is it safe to remove `-amdgpu`,`-ati`,`-nouveau`, `-radeon`, `-vesa`, and `-vmware` ones ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe. However first check (for example in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) if Intel's driver is actually used. Sometimes generic `vesa` driver is used instead of GPU-specific driver.

Comment: Good suggestion about the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. I've checked and Xorg apparently does load couple modules, `vesa` being among them.  I may attempt removing others and leaving `vesa` then. I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: Two part question here. "required" and "safe" so it might help to note what they're required for, if anything, even though it's safe to remove.